# Hot to parallelize for loof in for loop? Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize this equation:

```
def cosfunction(a,b):
     sumxx, sumxy, sumyy = 0, 0, 0
     for i in range(len(a)):
          x = a[i]
          y = b[i]
          sumxx += x*x
          sumyy += y*y
          sumxy += x*y
     return sumxy/math.sqrt(sumxx*sumyy)
     

def get_cosinesimilarity(vectrain, vectest):
     '''Calculates the cosine similarity for train and test'''
     x = vectrain 
     y = vectest 
     simlist = []
     for i in range(len(y)):
          sim = []
          listoftopten = [(0,0,0)] * 10
          for j in range(len(x)):
               cos = cosfunction(x[j],y[i])
               c = []
               for a in range(len(listoftopten)):
                    c.append(listoftopten[a][0])
               if cos > min(c):
                    listoftopten.remove(listoftopten[c.index(min(c))])
                    listoftopten.append((cos, x[j], y[i]))
          simlist.append(listoftopten)
     return simlist
```

I have to list which would be vectrain for train data and vectest for test data. They both contain data in a format like this [[0.012545, 0.58612, 0.7892],[0.4566, 0.4868, 0.789]] So basically vectors. In my get_cosinesimilarity function I want to calculate the cosine similarity for each test vector to each train vector. To then have a list returned with 10 tuples for each testvector that contain the tuple (cos, i, j) with cos being the cosine similarity and i being the vector of the trainset and j the vector of the testset. This is what I am appending to listoftopten. The lists with 10 tuples for each testvector are then appended to the simlist list, which will hold all the lists of top ten tuples for all the testvectors. It is very important that my output is of the format that I described simlist to be.

However as my vectest and vectrain lists are very long (up to 200.000 vectors) if I don't parallelize it it will take ages for the process to finish. I have never worked with multiprocessing in python before. Can someone please advise me on how to parallize this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expensive operation here seems to be the code following the computation of the cosine similarity. You may want to use **heap data structure** to get the top ten.

Here is an attempt to improve the performance (while ensuring low space complexity) by parallelizing cosine similarity computation. Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

```py
def cosfunction(*args):
    a = args[0]
    b = args[1]
    cos = 0
    # ... cos function implementation
    return cos, a, b

def insert_and_trim(heap, new_elements):
    # Please try this yourself.
    # iterate through each element in the new_elements list and insert into the heap
    # trim the heap to ensure heap doesn't bloat up in size
    # One method of doing the above is to create a "MAX HEAP". Insert the new_elements into the heap. get_max from the heap, until the heap contains, say 10 elements.
    pass

def get_top_ten(heap):
    # Please try this yourself.
    # Since it is a max heap, when you consecutively do get max from the heap, you get a descending order of the elements in the heap.
    pass 


def get_cosinesimilarity(vectrain, vectest):
     '''Calculates the cosine similarity for train and test'''
     x = vectrain 
     y = vectest 
     simlist = []
     for i in range(len(y)):
          sim = []
          heap = None # Create a heap by yourself; https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html
          listoftopten = [(0,0,0)] * 10
          BATCH_SIZE = 10 # set to any value of your choice. Capped by ulimit
          args_list = []
          for j in range(len(x)):
               if len(args_list) < BATCH_SIZE:
                   args_list.append((x[j],y[i]))
               else:
                   pool = Pool(BATCH_SIZE)
                   cos_list = pool.map(cosfunction, args_list)
                   insert_and_trim(heap, cos_list)
               
               # In case of say 14 elements, process the 4 elements in the end that broke out of the loop prematurely
               if len(args_list) > 0:
                   pool = Pool(BATCH_SIZE)
                   cos_list = pool.map(cosfunction, args_list)
                   insert_and_trim(heap, cos_list)
                   # insert_and_trim(listoftopten, cos_list)
           sim.append(get_top_ten(heap))
           # sim.append(get_top_ten(listoftopten))
     return sim
```

If you do not want to use heap then you could use your original implementation as below:

```py
def insert_and_trim(listoftopten, new_elements):
    # slightly modified code wrt question, following the cosine similarity computation
    c = []
    for cos, x, y in new_elements:
        for a in range(len(listoftopten)):
            c.append(listoftopten[a][0])
        if cos > min(c):
            listoftopten.remove(listoftopten[c.index(min(c))])
            listoftopten.append((cos, x, y))

def get_top_ten(listoftopten):
    return listoftopten
```